# Why is my PHP extension used by Symfony invalid after ubuntu update?

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu

I am working on a Symfony project. Yesterday an Ubuntu update (automatic) was executed and now, if I run

```
sudo composer install
```

then I get this error:

> The requested PHP extension ext-json ^1.6 has the wrong version
>   (7.4.1) installed. Install or enable PHP's json extension.

I have checked the extensions, like:

```
apt-cache search php | grep json
php7.2-json - JSON module for PHP
jsonlint - validating parser of JSON data structures
php-json-schema - implementation of JSON schema
php-services-json - PHP implementaion of json_encode/decode
php-json - JSON module for PHP [default]
php5.6-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.0-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.1-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.3-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.4-json - JSON module for PHP
```

and in composer.json I can see this line:

```
"ext-json": "^1.6",
```

How can I ensure that my extension is installed and enabled in the version composer expects it to be?

Comment: I guess you have to either change it to `"ext-json": "*"` to allow any version of the extension. This should be fine as the PHP-version should be enough to ensure the extension version works as expected. Otherwise you might want to check what version the more recent json extension has and then do something like `"ext-json": "^1.6|^2.0"` to allow both the newer and older version.

Comment: @dbrumann I get the same error. However, I would like to avoid changing composer.json and use the version specified in the file instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
"ext-json": "*",
```

If it's not your library and you cannot change the code, use

```
composer install -n --ignore-platform-reqs
```